# character on the end of a line in command prompt

Tags: java, command-line

I want to prompt the user for a percentage, and I want the percentage symbol to be on the end of that prompt as the user types. Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: Why do you want to read the symbol too? Just print it in the label, e.g. `Enter the amount in percentage (%): `

Comment: just for looks and to see if it's possible

Comment: While it may be possible using a separate thread in Java, think about the user experience. I for one would be confused and annoyed as to why I can't get rid of the `%` symbol from the prompt line (unless I read the description clearly).

Comment: it would go away once the user submitted the value. it's really just for academic purposes to see if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

In pure Java you can only respond to an input once the whole like has been input.

What you can do is write something like

```
System.out.print("Enter a percentage:      %\u0008\u0008\u0008\u0008");
```

which might position the cursor to after the `:` leaving the `%` after the prompt.  This depends on the type of console used.

If you want to get each character as it is typed or control the way it is displayed, you need to use a GUI interface such as Swing.